# DNN Upgrade 7 to 8 Error (DotNetNuke.UI.WebControls.SolPartActions)

Tags: c#, dotnetnuke

when i upgrade the my dnn web site its give the following error

Could Not Load Container: /Portals/_default/Containers/20067-UnlimitedColorsPack-049/No Title.ascx 
DotNetNuke.Services.Exceptions.ModuleLoadException: Unhandled error loading module.
 ---> System.Web.HttpParseException: Could not load type 'DotNetNuke.UI.WebControls.SolPartActions'.
 ---> System.Web.HttpParseException: Could not load type 'DotNetNuke.UI.WebControls.SolPartActions'.
 ---> System.Web.HttpException: Could not load type 'DotNetNuke.UI.WebControls.SolPartActions'.
 at System.Web.UI.TemplateParser.GetType(String typeName, Boolean ignoreCase, Boolean throwOnError)
 at System.Web.UI.TemplateParser.ProcessInheritsAttribute(String baseTypeName, String codeFileBaseTypeName, String src, Assembly assembly)
 at System.Web.UI.TemplateParser.PostProcessMainDirectiveAttributes(IDictionary parseData) --- End of inner exception stack trace
 --- at System.Web.UI.TemplateParser.ProcessException(Exception ex) at System.Web.UI.TemplateParser.ParseStringInternal(String text, Encoding fileEncoding)

Answer (score 3):

In DNN 8 Removed the Solpart so this causes raise .

please remove the following line in your Container file.

```
<%@ Register TagPrefix="dnn" TagName="ACTIONS"    Src="~/Admin/Containers/SolPartActions.ascx" %>

<dnn:ACTIONS runat="server" id="dnnACTIONS" />
```

For more information about DNN Release click [here](https://github.com/dnnsoftware/Dnn.Platform/releases)

Comment: wah mere sher bdiya

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the error I assume the site itself does work, only that the correct Container is not loaded.

For some reason DNN can't find the Container `No Title.ascx` located in `/Portals/_default/Containers/20067-UnlimitedColorsPack-049/`. Manually check if it is still there and if the folder is accessible for IIS and the AppPool.
If not you can do 3 things:

1. Create that folder again and copy a Container from another Container
   folder to that one and give it the same name.
2. Select a different default Container under "Site Settings >
   Appearance".
3. Reinstall the Container pack under "Host > Extensions"

If one of there does not solve your problem then there is something else going on and we'll have to look further.

Answer (score 0):

The key here is that the SolPart menu has been removed in DNN8.  Either of the answers you've received will work.  The first one, to remove references to SolPart from the container files should be fine, and not change behavior if the containers provide decoration that you want/need.

Might be a good time to revisit your skin/theme, as it's clearly an old one.